# Part of statement missing from sys.dm_exec_query_stats

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to debug the individual parts of a large query; I'm using the statement offsets in sys.dm_exec_query_stats to separate them. There is one particularly troublesome statement that for some reason is not present in sys.dm_exec_query_stats; it is, however, present in sys.dm_exec_requests. Is this expected behavior? Can I not get the query stats for that substring because it's currently executing? To be specific, this returns the executing part of the query:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where statement_start_offset = 29466
```

But this does not:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats where statement_start_offset = 29466
```

This is a production system and installing third-party tools or scripts is something I want to avoid unless absolutely necessary. Just looking to see if someone has thoughts about what could be going on with the DMVs here.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what might be going wrong with your script, since you didn't show us what you're running. But no matter -- you're probably better off using [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/), and doing something like this:

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @get_plans = 1,
    @get_full_inner_text = 1,
    @get_outer_command = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hadn't heard of this script before and it looks really interesting. But, I have no way of getting it into production readily.